# How to use environment variables set up in run config, inside the run time parameters within a JetBrains IDE

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am setting up environment variables in PyCharm's run configuration, but they do not resolve if I try to use them inside the parameters section. This doesn't make sense? Am I doing something wrong?

I've tried

- `--example $HELLO_WORLD$`
- `--example ${HELLO_WORLD}`
- `--example $HELLO_WORLD`

Then within environment variables I would have `HELLO_WORLD` declared. But in the run time stdout, I can see that an example program ran would be

```
stdout> example_script.py --example ${HELLO_WORLD}
```

So the environment variable is not resolving/replacing.

[image: Example]

Comment: 1º The `environment variables` field doesn't accept macros, [only the `parameters` field](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-python.html#1) does. 2º PyCharm doesn't have any macro to automatically read environment variables, you would have to [create your own macro as an external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-third-party-tools.html). (So that's 2 reasons already why you can't link `parameters` and `environment variables` like you're showing in the screenshot).

Comment: Also, if you set an environment variable it is set on the OS before the program is launched, so there's no reason to pass it as an invocation argument because the program would read the environment variable directly from the OS not from the arguments.

Comment: @bad_coder I ended up using the EnvFile plugin. The main appeal for this approach I wanted was an easily shareable config with minimal setup. But I guess I am using it in a way that's not supported